# Conjugacy Classes and Irreducible Representations

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

For finite groups number of inequivalent irreducible complex representations equals the number of conjugacy classes.

When the group is $S_n$ it is easy to see that both are available one each for every partition of $n$, into positive integers. So there is a direct correspondence between the two collections associated to the group.

For cyclic groups of order $n$, conjugacy classes are singletons, and hence for the conjugacy class of $g^k$ (g being a fixed generator of the group) one can associate the representation $g\mapsto e^{2\pi i k/n}$.

Is there any other group admitting similar  EXPLICIT CORRESPONDENCE between irreducible representations and conjugacy classes?

Comment: In $S_n$ you can biject both conjugacy classes and irreps to partitions of $n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: thanks, that is something I have mentioned in my post. My question is: is there a natural correspondence. Like Galois produced between intermediate fields and collection of subgroups of Galois groups? If not is this correspondence known for any other classes of groups?